# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare when switching themes

Tags: functions, fatal-error

I've built a theme from scratch which is named "core". Core has a child theme called "core_child". My child theme works perfectly and only contains the following:

1. /images
2. screenshot.png
3. style.css

Today I needed to activate "core" to make some changes. I received the following error upon activation:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_slug_body_class() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fresh_install/wp-content/themes/core/functions.php on line 3
```

The error indicates that I have a functions conflict. This prompted me to open up my `functions.php` file. I renamed the function `add_slug_body_class` to `body_slug_core` and this re-produced the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare body_slug_core() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fresh_install/wp-content/themes/core/functions.php on line 3
```

Here's the function which is causing the problem:

```
// Page slug body class
function body_slug_core( $classes ) {
global $post;
if ( isset( $post ) ) {
$classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_slug_core' );
```

Next I deleted the function completely. This produced the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare remove_default_image_sizes() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fresh_install/wp-content/themes/core/functions.php on line 23
```

This error is referring to the next function within `functions.php`. Here's the code:

```
// Remove WP default image sizes
function remove_default_image_sizes( $sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_default_image_sizes');
```

I repeated what I had tried for the first function (renaming and then deleting the function completely), but it simply flagged the next function as a conflict.

I have read that this can be caused by WordPress websites that have been compromised. This is not the case as I've only been running the themes locally via MAMP. I've changed the names of the functions which rule out any conflict with the WordPress core files.

I have tried a fresh install of WordPress with a clean database without any plugins running. To regain control of wp-admin, I have renamed the core theme folder to core_. This produces a further warning in wp-admin which may be unrelated:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fresh_install/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php on line 675
```

The warning disappears when I refresh the page.

WordPress Version: 3.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS for my parent theme (core) was incorrectly formatted. The code at the top read:

```
Theme Name: Core
Theme URI: http://www.domain.co.uk
Description:  The core theme.
Author: Squideyes
Author URI: http://www.domain.co.uk
Template: Core
Version: 1.0.0
Tags: clean, simple, easy
```

The `Template:` tag should only appear in the child theme css. This is what caused the functions conflict.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. When you're able (I think it's after 48 hours), be sure to mark your answer as **Accepted** so that it may help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @PatJ. I knew it would be down to a silly mistake that I'd made.